# how to insert if exist update (no unique key)

Tags: mysql, sql

i have 3 tables (sample),no key restrictions
one is FRUITTABLE, second is FRUITPRICE, third is COMBINATIONS
in FRUITTABLE, we insert what is being sold, color(ie,banana green or yellow),taste,
in FRUITPRICE, we insert how many piece, if applicable pack and the time it was sold

this is how i create combinations

```
SELECT FT.FRUITS,  FT.COLOR, FT.TASTE, COUNT(FP.SALES) AS TOTAL, FP.TIMESOLD
FROM FRUITSTABLE FT
JOIN FRUTSPRICE FP  ON FT.ID = FP.ID
WHERE FP.TIMESOLD BETWEEN '2013-12-01 11:00:00' AND '2013-12-01 12:00:00'
GROUP BY FT.FRUITS, FT.COLOR, FT.TASTE
```

in the COMBINATIONS table, what we do is we group it and count so we will see what is most likely good fruit combination per hour

SO COMBINATIONS WILL OCCUR ONCE EVERY HOUR

lets say

ie: mango,yellow,sour,10, 3:00PM
ie: mango,yellow,sour,12, 4:00PM
ie: mango,yellow,sour,14, 5:00PM
ie: mango,yellow,sour,10, 6:00PM

so evey hour, lets say 3:00PM
we insert 
mango,yellow,sour,1, 3:00PM
then another customer bought this combination at the same hour so the data will be
mango,yellow,sour,2, 3:00PM

now, in combinations, we insert it. but if the combination already exist,
i honestly dont know how i can update it.. 
we need to update it lets say every 5min, maybe i can manage to create SP and EVENT that will
call SP(hoping this is correct)

the only problem is i dont know how to:
select, insert, if exist(the combinations of FT.FRUITS, FT.COLOR, FT.TASTE are same) update

pls let me know if what im thinking is possible or not..
thanks in advance

PS. i already used insert on duplicate key update in some cases

PS. we determine the group combination and total sales(FP.SALES) per hour(TIMESOLD)

EDIT
PS replace into is not applicable as well

also the reason why i cant use a unique key is because it will be useless.. 
because each combination will occur every hour.. honestly, 
i already have solution. but it wont be updated every minute,
my solution will be insert it every hour. 
the negative side of doing that is the record in the webpage will not be in real time

all i need to figure out is how i can do something LIKE 
insert on duplicate key update (but without using primary key)
so that the table will be updated and the record will be in real time
if its possible to create a workaround

sorry if i have to edit the question many times. i hope this one is constructive.. thank you for your help guys...

Comment: Why are you not allowed to use a primary key?

Comment: One of the principles of normalization is to not store calculated values.  That being the case, why do you even need the combinations table?

Comment: Hi, this is just a sample, the reason is that, all combination is allowed, what is mostly bought per hour, day and month.. so the combination will occur once every hour

Comment: i removed ID in group by, thanks

Comment: You still haven't explained why you can't create a unique index? If you're not allowed to repeat a combination, create a unique index on that composite key.

Comment: Without a unique index, it's not possible to do what you want in a single query. You need one query to SELECT the row to see if it exists, then a second to UPDATE or INSERT. You can do this with a SP, or with code in a client language. To be totally safe you need to use a lock or transactions, to prevent a change to the table between the SELECT and INSERT.

Comment: hi, i cant create unique key because it will be useless.. because each combination will occur every hour.. honestly, i already have solution. but it wont be updated every minute, my solution will be insert it every hour. the negative side of doing that is the record in the webpage will not be in real time

Comment: hi, pls see the question again.. i change some.. sorry my bad

Comment: sorry for not being constructive, i have updated the question

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for this :

[Insert to table or update if exists (MySQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205181/insert-to-table-or-update-if-exists-mysql)

OR:

You can actually make the combination (of FT.FRUITS, FT.COLOR, FT.TASTE) a key such that they can individually have multiple values but there will be unique combinations of them in the table.

Comment: hi Wajahat, thanks for the answer but i cant use it because there are no unique keys in the table and we are not allowed to add unique key

Comment: Then you probably will have to use some kind of If else structure in the SQL statements, I don't exactly know how that is done.
But theoretically speaking, the key (primary, secondary, candidate) can be a single attribute or a combination of attributes and in your case I see the combination of 3 attributes as a candidate key, but you say you are not allowed to use that; that is bad.

Comment: ^^, yes, it is headache

Answer (score 0):

Creating a `Compound Key` http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_key would be the right solution. However, if you are not able to create keys for whatever reason, do it the other way round:

```
UPDATE myTable SET [whatever goes here] WHERE FRUITS = [currentFruit] AND COLOR = [currentColor] AND TASTE = [currentTaste]
```

Now, use your programing language and retrieve the `affected row count`. If it's 1 - you're done. If it's 0: You need to insert, because there was no row matching your update statement.

Comment: hi dognose, i just updated my question.. i will look on compound_key..hope it works, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, if you are using load data statement instead of insert(like reading from csv or customized delimited file). You can use the replace flag.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html